# Как закрыть доступ к файлу группе пользователей через lpSecurityAttributes в SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES?

Tags: winapi, безопасность, c++

Добрый день!

Моя задача состоит в том, чтобы запретить доступ группе пользователей к файлу через WinAPI.

Я использую функцию CreateFile.
Нашла, что в ней есть атрибут lpSecurityAttributes, который задает дескриптор безопасности.
Как я понимаю, через него можно задать доступ группе.

В Интернете смогла найти только описание SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES:

```
typedef struct _SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES {  
    DWORD  nLength; 
    LPVOID lpSecurityDescriptor; 
    BOOL   bInheritHandle; 
} SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES;
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти пример использования lpSecurityAttributes? Везде, где смотрю, примеры CreateFile вместо нужного мне параметра передают NULL.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379560(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @IceFox: Ну, вот, например: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms717798%28v=vs.85%29.aspx